# Mounting USB on boot causes error on boot on Pi4

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi, fstab

I am attempting to mount a usb drive to a specific directory at boot time so that it's mapped to the same directory each time. I read this article, https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36824/automounting-usb-drive-on-boot, that says to add it to /etc/fstab

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=bf444af9-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=bf444af9-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
UUID=b994a97c-027d-465e-8483-ad519866f87c /mnt/usb2 ext4 defaults,umask=000 0 0
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

I tried both PARTUUID and UUID, same results both times.

Here's what I've tried:

```
PARTUUID=b994a97c-027d-465e-8483-ad519866f87c /mnt/usb2 ext4 defaults,umask=000 0 0
PARTUUID=fc69e031-8593-4c67-9cf9-c364d0166117 /mnt/usb2 ext4 defaults,umask=000 0 0
UUID=b994a97c-027d-465e-8483-ad519866f87c /mnt/usb2 ext4 defaults,umask=000 0 0
UUID=fc69e031-8593-4c67-9cf9-c364d0166117 /mnt/usb2 ext4 defaults,umask=000 0 0
```

When I restart, it is giving this error:

> Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.

I got out of this by modifying the cmdline.txt and adding bash.

I did a `blkid` to see my usb drive UUID. Here is what I got:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo blkid
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="boot" LABEL="boot" UUID="6284-658D" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="bf444af9-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="3a324232-335f-4617-84c3-d4889840dc93" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bf444af9-02"
/dev/sda2: UUID="b994a97c-027d-465e-8483-ad519866f87c" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="fc69e031-8593-4c67-9cf9-c364d0166117"
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="bf444af9" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sda1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="4792d598-bd1e-4784-99a5-27db1f5d937b"
```

What am I doing wrong? I cannot get this usb drive to mount at boot up to a specific directory.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Remove `umask=000` from your `fstab` entry.  This is not a valid mount option for an ext4 filesystem.  The `umask` option is only available on filesystems like FAT and NTFS that do not support Unix permissions.

**Additional details**:  The error you're getting indicates that system startup failed, but `root` isn't allowed to log in with a password, so systemd won't start a recovery shell.  First step would be to boot with `init=/bin/bash` added to the kernel command line (which it sounds like you've already done) to boot into a root shell, and then run `passwd root` to set a root password.  Then reboot, and you should be allowed to log in to a recovery shell that you can use to debug.

Once you're logged in to the recovery shell, you can inspect the logs to see what failed.  `journalctl -u mnt-usb2.mount` and `journalctl -b` are probably going to be the most useful things to look at.  You can also try mounting manually with `mount /mnt/usb2`.  In your case, before removing the `umask` option, this should result in an error like this:

```
mount: /mnt/usb2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Remove `umask=000` from the `fstab` entry, and try manually mounting again.  Most likely it will work.

I'd recommend you add `nofail` to the options for your USB filesystem.  This will allow your system to boot normally if the filesystem can't be mounted for any reason.  (You can also leave out `defaults` if you'd like.  This is only necessary if you have no other options.)

So in summary, here's what I suggest you put in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=b994a97c-027d-465e-8483-ad519866f87c /mnt/usb2 ext4 nofail 0 0
```